# Prevent open when click v-btn in v-expansion-panel headers

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
test (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('foo')
},
```

```html
<v-expansion-panel>
  <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <div slot="header">
      <v-btn icon flat @click="test($event)"><v-icon>add</v-icon></v-btn>
      title
    </div>
    <contents />
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

This is v-expansion-panel with action button in it's header.

When I click action button, expansion panel is opened.

Can I have expansion panel doesn't open when I click the button?

Answer (score 18):

By using `@click.native.stop` on `v-btn` your button click will work and your expansion panel will not open.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is by using `@click.stop=""`

Answer (score -3):

Sorry.

I didn't know stopPropagation method.